# Is weather.com still running Drupal?

Tags: 7

There have been news items in 2013 about weather.com moving to Drupal. I have been reading [How to tell if a site is using Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/how-to-tell-if-a-site-is-using-drupal-7) and I have been unable to find out if the site is still running on Drupal.

How can I find out if weather.com is still running Drupal?

Comment: see: https://austin2014.drupal.org/session/migrating-worlds-largest-website-drupal-weathercom

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because if you check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic all on topic questions are about something you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but we are not going to open a new question for each site that could use Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I use [buildwith chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn?hl=en) and [Appspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae?hl=en), it does not looks like they use drupal CMS.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually some CDATA starting with

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings
```

Or the files and folders are in a /sites/all/.. directory that are the major drupal give aways.

It does not look like weather.com uses drupal.

Answer (score -1):

Is not Drupal. IMHO is a custom php framework based on YUI library.